# Union of two queries with the first query resultset getting the first ten rownums in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, union, rownum

I want Union of two queries with the first query resultset getting the first ten rownums in Oracle.
Example:
Like if first query has 10 rows and max rownum is 10.I want second query rownum to be started from 11 in the result of union.

Comment: In other words, you want to make sure the first ten rows of the UNIONed result set come from the subquery that is on the left side of UNION?

Comment: rownum is a pseudocolumn, the rows that are selected depend on your ordering (order by), not by saying ...and rownum <= 10...  when you say "I want second query rownum to be started from 11" it is meaningless to the data in the table, as much as saying "I want second query rownum to be started from 158"...order by is whats important here...  Please post an example of the table (or tables?) you are referring and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    table1
        ORDER BY
                col1
        )
WHERE   rownum <= 10
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, rownum AS rn
        FROM    (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    table2
                ORDER BY
                        col2
                )
        )
WHERE   rn > 10
```

Comment: What can be done if the number of rows in the first query is not fixed? Do we use max??